# Including subpages by GET parameter in JSP

Tags: jsp, include, get

I'm learning JSP and I want to include subpage (on div named "content") based on GET method generated by menu link.

```
<div id="menu">
   <a href="/index.jsp?page=1">Subpage 2</a>
</div>
<div id="content>

   //include somehow subpage s2.sjp

</div>
```

I've done somethink like that:

```
    <%
            int par = 0;
            String which = "blank.jsp" ;
            if (request.getParameter("page") != null) {
                par = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("page"));
            }
                switch (par) {
                    case 0:
                        which = "blank.jsp";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        which = "s2.jsp";
                        break;
                }

    %>
```

but I'm not sure if that is proper way to solve my problem in JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) in `<jsp:include>`.

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/${param.page}.jsp" />
```

Calling `foo.jsp?page=bar` will let `${param.page}` resolve to `bar` and this `<jsp:include>` will then effectively include `/WEB-INF/bar.jsp`. No need for complex checks on numbers. Just use the filename as parameter.

Note that the include JSP is been placed in `/WEB-INF` folder to prevent endusers from being able to open it directly by  either purposefully or accidently calling its URL in browser address bar.

You can put it in a [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:catch>` to prevent an exception from being thrown if the file doesn't exist.